# Breaking down vector by line segments using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

A few colleagues and I are trying to break down a vectorized road network that is all connected (as if it is one polygon) and we are trying to break it down into multiple segments based off of a line dataset.

Is there a way that we could potentially do this?

Comment: The use of the word "polygon" has me confused. Is your road layer made up of lines or polygons?  If the former, may I suggest that you edit your post to remove any reference to polygons?

Comment: We have a polygonal road layer that was generated from the raster -> polygon tool we received from rasterized road data in a zoning shapefile. We also have line data that is broken down into road segments (which is what we want for our vector data) and has the attributes we want. We simply want to break down the vectorized road data similarly to the line data and are unsure of how to proceed. Identity did not work due to the fact they are not the same in structure (polygon vs. line) and spatial join simply combined the attribute based on spatial overlay.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question instead of commenting on your own post. "Best" questions are generally problematic here, as they are often closed for being *opinion-based*.

Comment: Shucks, I'm now more confused than before!  It *appears* that you have **two** representations of the road network: linear and polygonal.  Am I correct?  If so, why is a polygonal version required when roads are traditionally represented as lines?  Furthermore, what does "... break down the vectorized .." mean; specifically what do you mean by "break down" and which layer (linear? polygonal? something else?) are you trying to "break down"?  Please edit your original post to be clearer.  Screenshots would also assist.

Comment: This sounds like linear referencing, and that your mention of and tag for polygon are obscuring your question.

Comment: Both euclidean and cost allocation will do the job, however cost allocation is much faster and stable.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using cost allocation tool from Spatial Analyst. Populate short integer field in polygons by 1. Convert polygons to raster, using this field. Expand raster by 1 cell, output is your cost raster in cost allocation (CA) tool.

Use it and road centrelines as source in CA.

Input:

[image]

Output cost allocation raster:

[image]

You can convert allocation raster to polygons, clip it by original polygon and transfer line attributes using field join, e.g.:

[image]